# Http file upload in asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-mvc-2, file-upload

I have simple http form to upload file using http input tag as below:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
   {%>
     <label for="file"> Select File :</label>
     <input type="file" name="uploadedFile" value="" accept="text/plain" class="fileUpload" />
     <input id="btnAdd" type="submit" class="button" name="Add" value=" Add "/>
<% } %>
```

and back in controller I have a corresponding Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(HttpPostedFileBase uploadedFile)
{
    Logger.Debug("Inside Add");

    ProductModel model = new ProductModel();

    if (uploadedFile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"),
                                       Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName));
        Logger.Debug("File saved at - " + filePath);
        uploadedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
        model.FileName = uploadedFile.FileName;
        model.Add(filePath);
        return View("Result", model);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

On my development machine and on lab server, this works perfectly. But on production it does not even send any request for submit button. I inspected requests through fiddler, it does not show any traces that request is even originating for this form, from IE 8 on win 2008 r2 production server.

I'm clueless here. What could be the issue? Do you think IE security permissions, UAC, group policies might be an issue? or you have something else to say.

Comment: Tried another browser like chrome, and watch the console log messages?

Comment: Nope. good point. But fiddler gives same effect. It does not show any communication happening between the browser and IIS

Comment: I suspect there might be some javascript errors preventing the form submit

Comment: I agree, my guess would be that there is some javascript validation that is not apparent.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the name of the file input from `uploadFile` to `UploadedFile` in the View

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
   {%>
     <label for="file"> Select File :</label>
     <input type="file" name="UploadedFile" value="" accept="text/plain" class="fileUpload" />
     <input id="btnAdd" type="submit" class="button" name="Add" value=" Add "/>
<% } %>
```

Comment: That's refactoring that I did, earlier it was 'uploadFile' at both places. This does not change anything.